# How do effect the same youtube app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

**why know how can I develop the same effects?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this control: [Sidepanel](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jasidepanels). It does similar to what you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, it is that what i found. but, Will it work on devices with iOS 5.0?